# How to change form display from = to :?

Tags: javascript

is there anyway that I can change the output from

Name: =daniel to Name: Daniel for all of the followings?

Picture in this URL > https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTy4Y.jpg

```
 <h2>Your details have been submitted!</h2>
 <h2>You have entered the following data: </h2>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var formData = location.search;
    formData = formData.substring(1, formData.length);
    while (formData.indexOf("+") != -1) {
        formData = formData.replace("+", " ");
    }

    formData = unescape(formData);
    var formArray = formData.split("&");
    document.write("<p>");
    for (var i = 0; i < formArray.length; ++i) {
        document.writeln(formArray[i] + "<br />");
    }
    document.write("</p>");

</script>
```

Comment: you can check if its alphanumeric, you can captalize the the string

Comment: you shouldn't use document.write().

Comment: @Godisgood That helps no one. While I agree, provide some reasoning

Comment: Use innerHTML instead.  `document.write()` clears the current html from the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, but this won't get you very far.
Change this line:

```
document.writeln(formArray[i] + "<br />");
```

to

```
document.writeln(formArray[i].replace("=", ": ") + "<br />");
```

But if I were you I would work on parsing the data into an actually usable object for further manipulation, currently you only work by doing String manipulations on the page URL.

**Edit**: To expand on the question you posted in the comment to this post:

To begin, you should try to move away from moving data via URL or GET requests, as these are quite visible, restrictive in encoding, prone to manipulation and recording. Especially data like credit card information should not be embedded in URLs.

Anyhow, in regard to parsing let's start with splitting your formArray further and storing the key-value pairs in an object:

```
var formArray = formData.split("&");
var formDataObj = {};  //in this we will store the data

//let's assume here that you have no key duplicates in your data
//and that it is always properly formatted
formArray.forEach(function (item) {
    var key = item.split("=")[0];
    var value = item.split("=")[1];
    formDataObj[key] = value;
});

//if you processed your data like this you can then access it more precisely like so
document.writeln("<p>Customer " + formDataObj.customerNumber + " has card number " + formDataObj.cardNumber + "</p>");
```

I think it's obvious how this can be advantageous.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot! I just followed my textbook and my teacher didn't really teach much javascript at all. Do you recommend any tutorials on parsing the data into an actually usable object for further manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a helper function

```
function capitalize(a)
{
return a[0].toUpperCase() + a.slice(1);
}
```